# sudden "license checkout failed" with java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection

Tags: java, mysql, database, matlab

I am running and maintainig a Matlab application that builds upon MySQL database access. All of a sudden, after 8 years of successful database connection, I'am getting a "Licensing error: -18,147" indicating that no Communications Toolbox is installed and licensed. While this TB had never ever been installed on the machine, since three weeks, this error is thrown with all three Matlab-Versions (2012b, 2015a, 2016b) available on the machine.

The error occurs at compile time (JIT) and only with the following line

```
 this.dbCon = java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(this.dbUrl, this.dbUsr, this.dbPwd);
```

Commenting the line out, does away with the error, but of course doesn't solve the problem. Any hints or ideas, how this can happen all of a sudden with a piece of code that hasn't changed for years, and is obviously not even native Matlab?

Rudolf

Comment: What kind of MATLAB license are you using? How did you buy it?

Comment: It's an academic license, and our IT infrastructure uses a dedicated license server with license pooling for a large number of installations.

Answer (score 0):

The problem had a very diffuse solution, which can not be called a real solution at all, and I also do not know whether it is sustainable or not.
To me, MATLAB seems to blacklist first individual files and then the whole directory for some unknown reason, if it encounters a license problem.

While poking around - commenting out lines, renaming files, copying code into new files and so on - I suddenly realized at some point that error -18 also occured immediately, when I tried to save some harmless new function into the application directory that contained the code with the "faulty" command. Finally it turned out that even an empty new file produced the license error - albeit not every file in the directory:

```
>> which AppDB
C:\Users\rudolf\Documents\App\AppDB.m  % AppDB constructor
>> which testFunc
C:\Users\rudolf\Documents\App\testFunc.m  % Has no license available
>> which emptyfile
C:\Users\rudolf\Documents\App\emptyfile.m  % Has no license available
```

In the next step I moved all files into a different directory, to find out that MATLAB still insisted on error -18. Then I started to move back the files into the AppDB folder one by one first, and checked the license of each using "which". To my surprise, emptyfile.m had no license problem any more, and none of the others. The application runs again with full sql-Access, and to be honest, I feel a bit duped by the Matlab license management, as I don't see any reasons why the problem arose and why it disappeared.

Conclusion: Matlab seems to use some (faulty) internal protection mechanism to blacklist a folder with alleged license problems. New files in this folder will also be blacklisted immediately. Moving all files to another folder will also blacklist this folder (as it contains blacklisted files). Moving back a file that is not blacklisted, will whitelist the original folder again. After that also blacklisted files can be moved back and get whitelisted.